# IE6 - DIV with class and ID

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<div id="nav" class="red">

some more HTML here

</div>
```

The following CSS:

```
#nav.red {
background: red;
}
```

However this does not work in IE6, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this moment it is unknown why this is the case, and there is no real 'fix'. You just have to work around it by changing your CSS. For example:

```
#nav{
   /*basic styles*/
}
   .red{
      /* stylings */
   }
   .blue{
      /* stylings */
   }
   .contact{
      /* stylings */
   }
   .news{
      /* stylings */
   }
```

See [here](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=MultipleIdClassBug) for more, and [here](http://host.sonspring.com/multi-class/page_5.htm) for a test page.

Answer (score 1):

just use

<strike>#nav</strike>

```
.red { 
    background: red; 
}
```

Comment: I cant do that, I want nav to be any colour I want based on the class I add.

Comment: use ".red { background: red; }" instead then

Comment: Bad code, what if you wanted to change the colour scheme? Changing all your classes is bad. Better: semantic names.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ie7.js to fix the bug. It makes IE6 behave more like IE7. It should fix atleast the multiple classes-problem, so might work for #id.class also.
[More info about ie7.js](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/)

Otherwise, you have to work around it. For example

```
<div id="nav">
   <span class="red">hep</span>
   <span>hep</span>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
#nav {}
#nav span {color:#000;}
#nav .red {color:#f00;}
```

Or if you can, you could just do the colour-changing with the .red and use #nav for the common layout-stuff. eg.

```
#nav {float:left; padding:10;}
.red {background: #f00;}
.blue {background: #00f;}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a mistake.
Try this:

```
#nav, .red {
background: red;
}
```

Comment: That styles both the `#nav` div (regardless of class) and anything else that might have the `red` class.